# How to call function when I select date in table filter? Angular PrimeNG library

Tags: angular, primeng

So I have a filter like this:

```
 <p-columnFilter [type]="col.type" [field]="col.field" display="menu" class="p-ml-auto"></p-columnFilter>
```

I want to call a function when I pick a date. What I want achieve is server side filtering.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your html you need to add below events

1. onSelect - Callback to invoke when a date is selected from datepicker
2. onInput - Callback to invoke when the user enetrs date manually

html file

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" (onSelect)="datePickedFromPicker($event)" (onInput)="dateEnteredManually($event)"></p-calendar>
```

Inside the class in ts file

```
datePickedFromPicker($event) {

// do something

}

dateEnteredManually($event) {

// do something

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Functions are not even called.

Comment: My bad, I have updated the answer. The events which I mentioned in the answer are for `<p-calender></p-calender>`. I didn't observed that you're using other directive. Add those events in the p-calender directive and once the user selects the date you can apply the filteration